# Is there a distribution optimized for heavy data traffic?

Tags: performance

I am testing an Android app which sends minute-by-minute updates to my Drupal site which acts as a server.

I create a single node each day and all my app data is saved in CCK fields within that node.

I got the updates working yesterday and tested for half a day. When I try to edit the node, to see the CCK data uploaded, my site crashed and complained of lack of PHP memory.

In my .htaccess file, I had set PHP memory to 100M. I then increased it to 300M and then 500M with no improvements. Then I tried 1000M. It worked but it seems slow.

That's just for one user's half a day's worth of data. Eventually, I will have hundreds of users with 24hours data each.

Can anyone tell me if there is a Drupal distribution which handles heavy data traffic by design?

Comment: are you the only person testing your Drupal and do you need 1000M?. may be do you have some issue with your server/Drupal/App configuration. (sorry if I do not understand you)

Comment: Sounds like you're using CCK fields for something they were not designed to be used for. An optimized distribution can't fix architecture problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a look at [Pressflow](http://pressflow.org/).

> Pressflow is a distribution of Drupal with integrated performance, scalability, availability, and testing enhancements.

Comment: PressFlow is a great distro, specially for D6, but I'd still think looking at your structure again would help you to prevent a lot of future frustrations.

Answer (score 1):

Bojan put it right in a comment above. I just think its important to explain it again, in case someone finds this in the future :)

I think the problem here is rather in the design. If I get it right, you are saving all the data from 1 day into 1 node ?

When you attempt to load such one node, drupal loads all the data in memory, so I am afraid that no settings and distributions can save you, you just have to change the design - probably having 2 types - 1 for the day and 2nd for the data entries.

You might as well try something "lighter" for the data - such as the [data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module.